# Prove that $f(t,x)=t^{2}e^{nx^2}$ is Lipschitz with respect to the second variable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, cauchy-principal-value

I would like to prove (if so), that the function $f(t,x)=t^{2}e^{nx^2}$ for $t_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is Lipschitz with respect to the second variable $x$.

> I tried bounding it but I can't seem to do so
> $$|t^{2}e^{nx^2}-t^{2}e^{ny^2}|=t^2|e^{nx^2}-e^{ny^2}|=2t^2|n\xi e^{n\xi^2}||x-y|$$
> Because for large $n$ or $t$ I can't figure out an upper bound.

Anything will help thank you.

Comment: If $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, then 
$$\sup\{\frac{|g(x) - g(y)|}{|x - y|} : x, y \in \mathbb{R}, x \neq y\} = \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|g'(x)|.$$
So your problem reduces to showing whether $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|\partial_{x}f_n(t_0, x)| < \infty$.

Comment: Where is $x$ varying? If it is bounded, it follows from the fact that the derivative is bounded. On the other hand, ifthe domain of definition is unbounded, then the statement is just wrong.

Comment: @Mason Yes, you are right. But i end up with the same thing. $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t_0,x)=2xnt_{0}^{2}e^{nx^2}$$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I supose that one has to study the cases for $n$ and then study the interval of definition using this hypotheses but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Is $n$ negative like in the previous question about this DE? Is locally Lipschitz sufficient for the start?